# high and low frequencies 1's and 0's?

Tags: rf

Do RF waves send data by high and low frequencies ? So a low frequency represents a 0 and a high frequency wave represents a 1 ? Then what would be considered a low and high frequency ? In what part of the RF spectrum would a high and low frequency fall within ?

Comment: Some do. It's called FM (frequency modulation). The low frequency would be the lower of the frequencies, which would be in the spectrum somewhere, and the high frequency would be the higher of the frequencies.

Comment: Tom thanks but where in the RF spectrum ??

Comment: Somewhere between 0Hz and infinity Hz. How long is a piece of string?

Comment: In FM or FSK, "low" means "below the carrier frequency" and "high" means "above the carrier frequency".  And very very loosely, if it's only 1Hz below and 1Hz above, then telling whether it's low or high takes about a second, so you can only transmit 1 bit per second. Higher transmission rates need a wider channel around the carrier.

Answer (score 1):

That's a lot of questions!

> Do RF waves send data by high and low frequencies?

That's one way to do it; it's called FSK (frequency-shift keying). It isn't actually a very common way, because it isn't very efficient. One example would be RTTY (radio teletype) signals transmitted by ham radio operators.

> So a low frequency represents a 0 and a high frequency wave represents a 1?

Maybe, but the opposite could just as well be true. The assignment is arbitrary.

> Then what would be considered a low and high frequency? In what part of the RF spectrum would a high and low frequency fall within?

Usually a relatively small offset (100 Hz to 1000 Hz) is applied to whatever RF carrier you've chosen. It could be in any part of the RF spectrum that meets the application requirements and whatever licensing is required.

Comment: Dave@ thanks. Can such a communication channel deploy an encryption scheme and if yes can the type of encryption be any at all that is commercially used ? Also if video and data are being transmitted together can any type of encryption scheme be used along with some form of compression together ?

Comment: Dave@ one other question what other methods can be used to transmit 1's and 0's via RF waves ?

Comment: @user121309, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulation#List_of_common_digital_modulation_techniques

Comment: To the OP: FSK is a type of frequency modulation (FM). So 
Tom's comment is consistent with this answer.

Answer (score 1):

Encryption (or not) and which type of encryption are completely independent of the modulation scheme. Neither the modulation scheme or the encryption scheme imply, enable, or prohibit the other.

You will find that when digital audio and video are sent together, the two bit-streams are first compressed and then combined into a single stream by one of several prescribed standards (i.e. Codecs). And then the combined, compressed bit-stream is encrypted. If you think about what it takes at the receiving end to extract the original audio and video bit-streams, you will see why this is the most common method and sequence.

There are dozens of common RF modulation techniques for digital data. Frequency-shift keying (FSK) as you are asking about is still used in modified form for digital communication. (Thanks to Chris Stratton for reminding me.)

Comment: Actually there is a lot of FSK used today, especially if you consider things like GFSK and MSK which are enhancements of it.  For that matters there's still a lot of on-off keying in use, too.